# MySQL select performance with Indexes degrades for similar queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a schema

```
applicants - id, max_res_id, max_visa_id
applicant_files - id, applicatid, fileid, filetype
files - id, name, filetype
```

applicants -

```
CREATE TABLE `applicants` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `max_res_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `max_visa_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_res_id` (`max_res_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_visa_id` (`max_visa_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

applicant_files

```
CREATE TABLE `applicant_files` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `applicantid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `filetype` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `q_applicantfile_fileid` (`fileid`),
  KEY `u_applicantfile_applid` (`applicantid`),
  KEY `idx_filetype` (`filetype`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

files

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `filetype` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_filetype` (`filetype`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`max_res_id, max_visa_id` referes to "id" of `applicant_files`
`fileid` refers to "id" of `files`

Now I have 2 different queries -

```
select  f.id as resumeId, f.name as resumeName, f.date_entered as resumeDate,
        a.id as applId
    from  oepl_applicants a
    inner join  applicant_files af
              ON ( a.id in ('id1', 'id2')
              and  a.id = af.applicantid
              and  a.max_res_id = af.id
              and  af.filetype = 1
              and  a.max_res_id != ''
              and  a.max_res_id is not null )
    inner join  files f
              ON ( af.fileid = f.id
              and  f.filetype = 1 ) 
select  f.id as visaId, f.name as visaName, f.date_entered as visaDate,
        a.id as applId
    from  oepl_applicants a
    inner join  applicant_files af 
              ON ( a.id in ('id1', 'id2')
              and  a.id = af.applicantid
              and  a.max_visa_id = af.id
              and  af.filetype = 2
              and  a.max_visa_id != ''
              and  a.max_visa_id is not null )
    inner join  files f 
              ON ( af.fileid = f.id
              and  f.filetype = 2 )
```

For 200 ids (id1, id2, ... id200), first query is returning results in 2 sec, while second query is returning results in 30 sec.

What can be going wrong here?

The only difference here in these 2 queries is the filetype is different, and join is on 2 different columns.
PS - a lot of values in max_visa_id is null (empty) as compared to values in max_res_id

Comment: Why are the primary keys string values? ...and why string values using different character sets?

Comment: you have column is yoru query that i don't see in your schema   .. ( eg: f.deleted ) are your sure this is the right schema

Comment: @scaisEdge: The schema shown here is a minified version. I have a lot of other columns in my tables. For the purpose of discussion here, consider that there is a "deleted" flag in every table.

Comment: @Uueerdo: id are UUIDs. those are char(36). My db schema supports utf8 default collation. I am sure this question has got nothing to do with charset. Am I right?

Comment: @scaisEdge: Edited my queries.

Comment: `applicant_files`.`id` uses latin1 instead of the tables' utf8 default; I just was thinking with the different charsets, MySQL may end up needing to convert one to the other before doing the comparison.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal I would update all the relevant columns with different charsets to instead use the same set (latin1, for the best speed). Then compare how it performs. The byte size difference between utf8 and latin1, plus the conversion that Uueerdo pointed out will certainly have an impact on performance, and many times a huge one.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Good catch. I overlooked that. But even if that is that case, why is one query performing well, while other doesnt. Since the joins are on the same table with same columns in "applicant_files"

Comment: @NalinAgrawal To answer that we would need to see the EXPLAIN plans for each of the 2 queries. My guess is that since the only difference is the `filetype` that is being searched for, that one file type is more selective than the other, so the optimizer uses a full table scan for one and uses the index for the other. Running EXPLAIN on each of the queries will reveal whether that, or some other explanation, is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the `CREATE TABLEs`.

Joining on `latin1` vs `utf8` invalidates the use of indexes!

Although it does not matter in this case, please move the "filtering" clauses to a `WHERE` clause and leave only the clauses that describe how the tables are related in the `ON` clause.  For example, in the first query:

```
    inner join  applicant_files af
              ON   a.id = af.applicantid
              and  a.max_res_id = af.id
    inner join  files f  ON  af.fileid = f.id
            WHERE  a.id in ('id1', 'id2')
              and  f.filetype = 1
              and  af.filetype = 1
              and  a.max_res_id != ''
              and  a.max_res_id is not null
```

The Optimizer will decide what order to look at the tables.  From the "filtering" clauses, it would like to see these:

```
a:        INDEX(max_res_id, id)
af and f: INDEX(filetype)  -- but see note below
```

Then the Optimizer will see if it is easy to get to the 'next' table.  These could be beneficial.  (I am noticing that you already have `(id)`.)

```
af:  INDEX(applicantid, filetype)  -- in either order
```

Please run `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see what order the Optimizer picked, and what index it picked to get to each subsequent table.

`char(36)` smells like a UUID or GUID.  It is good that you made them `CHARACTER SET latin1` instead of `utf8`.  But such fields are terrible for indexing due to the randomness.  See [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) .  If possible switch to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` though it would involve a lot of code and schema changes.

Are the two instances of `filetype` redundant?  That is, do you need to check both tables for the filetype?  That is a lot of extra work.

To help with the initial query, we need to understant the distribution of values of `filetype`.  Is `1` a lot more (or less) common than `2`?  Are the rows with `1` (or `2`) clumped near the start (or end) of the table?

How big are the tables?  What is the value if `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Some or all of the following *may* be conspiring to give you poor performance:

- Randomness of UUIDs.
- Tables larger than will fit in the buffer_pool.
- Not enough RAM to make the buffer_pool large.
- The buffer_pool is so large (relative to RAM) that swapping is occurring.

If those comments fail to provide enough speed, I will recommend restructuring the query to delay fetching from `f`:

```
SELECT f..., x...
    FROM (
        SELECT ... FROM applicants AS a
                   JOIN applicant_files AS af ON ...
                 WHERE ...
         ) AS x
    JOIN files AS f  ON x.fileid = f.id
    WHERE f.filetype = 1
```

*Caveat*:  " The schema shown here is a minified version. " -- *What I recommend may not be sufficient due to your minification!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. Please give me some time to get back to you. We have a production deployment and bug fixing today, so super busy in that. Appreciate your inputs.